# What is this bounty challenge on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Today I opened up this link https://hackerone.com/ibb-python?type=team&view_policy=true and it says it's a bounty challenge on Python but I couldn't understand the details. What is it saying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bug bounty programs on HackerOne are made for cybersecurity specialists. You hack some program - vendor pays you for that. Often are many rules what you can and can't do to get the reward.
There are 2 main rules:

1. You don't tell anyone about the security problem you found until the vendor allows you to do that. (It can never happen)
2. You don't try to make any benefits on found problem except the BugBounty payout.

So this python challenge is to find vulnerabilities in python language and python standard lib modules. Honestly, I don't recommend trying to do something if you hear about BugBounty program for the first time .

Comment: Thanks, man. I know I'm very far from doing that but curious to know about it.